# Android : Class not found when unmarshalling java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, parcelable

My class PhotosList:

```
public class PhotosList extends DataList<Photo> {

public PhotosList() {}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public PhotosList(Parcel source) {
    super(source);
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    source.readList(items, Photo.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    dest.writeList(items);
}

...
```

My class Photo:

```
public class Photo extends BaseModel {

@SerializedName("photos")
public ArrayList<Image> images;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public Photo() {}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public Photo(Parcel source) {
    super(source);
    images = new ArrayList<>();
    source.readList(images, Image.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    dest.writeList(images);
}

...
```

My class DataList:

```
public class DataList<T> implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("total_count")
public int total;

@SerializedName("message")
public String message;

@SerializedName("items")
public ArrayList<T> items;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public DataList() {}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public DataList(Parcel source) {
    total = source.readInt();
    message = source.readString();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(total);
    dest.writeString(message);
}
```

And I have this error:

> Class not found when unmarshalling: com.xxx.model.PhotosList
>                                            java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.model.PhotosList
>                                                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404)
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
>                                                at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
>                                                at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920)
>                                                at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6183)
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2707)
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2169)
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6322)
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6100)
>                                                at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170)
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3990)
>                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
>                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.model.PhotosList
>                                                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>                                                at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404) 
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358) 
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264) 
>                                                at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614) 
>                                                at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
>                                                at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920) 
>                                                at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6183) 
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2707) 
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2169) 
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6322) 
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6100) 
>                                                at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170) 
>                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3990) 
>                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
>                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

I get back the photolist object like that:

```
getIntent().setExtrasClassLoader(PhotosList.class.getClassLoader());
        PhotosList photosList = bundle.getParcelable(BUNDLE_KEY_PHOTOS);
```

Comment: Custom `Parcelable` objects work in some cases and not in others. Basically, foreign processes cannot work with them, because they do not have access to your class. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html). It is unclear where `bundle` comes from and where exactly the crash is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

you should refer to this article, read starting at "Parcelable, the Speed King". You are missing `describeContents()` and an inner class declaration `Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableDeveloper> CREATOR`

Comment: No, I didn't add these element in this post. In my real code I have these elements.

Comment: Please edit your code to show the implementation to receive the best support available to you.

Comment: It wouldn't compile if he was missing it